# Отметить элементы, у которых нет потомков

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется документ с текстом. Текст разбит на параграфы, в параграфах есть различные другие теги. Необходимо найти все теги, внутри которых нет других тегов и отметить их, например, темненьким бекграундом при наведении мышки. Каким образом с помощью jquery можно выполнить такой поиск?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0, il = a.length; i < il; ++i){
    if(!a[i].childNodes.length){
        a[i].onmouseover = function(){
            this.className += ' hilite';
        };
        a[i].onmouseout = function(){
            this.className = this.className.replace(' hilite', '');
        };
    }
}
```

В принципе, можете повесить события другим способом. Второй вариант:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0, il = a.length; i < il; ++i){
    if(!a[i].childNodes.length){
        this.className += ' hilite';
    }
}

css:
.hilite:hover{background:#666}
```